# Linux Domain to new WinServer03 Domain without affect users?

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, domain, migration, controller

I have to rebuild 2 Linux domain controllers to windows as they're not working and have lots of issues. Also, the company has changed hands and requires a new domain name anyway.

I've rebuilt one with WinServer03

My question is if I give the Windows box a new IP and Domain name will it affect clients currently on the network on the old domain? If they're not pointed at it they shouldn't have any trouble should they?

So if I build this new domain along side the linux one, with new DNS server and a fresh I.P i can migrate users over with minimum hassle??

It's probably very easy just don't wanna bring the whole deck of cards down during working hours.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking if you can "seamlessly" migrate computer and user accounts from a Samba domain into an Active Directory domain.

Current "stable" versions of Samba don't emulate an Active Directory domain, but rather act like a Windows NT 4.0 domain. You won't be able to just "upgrade" the Samba domain to Active Directory (although I'm getting a perverse desire to put up a Samba domain, join an NT 4.0 BDC to it, promote the NT 4.0 BDC to a PDC, remove the Samba BDC, and upgrade the Windows NT 4.0 machine to Windows Server 2003 just to see what would happen).

Your best bet, since you want to build the Windows Server 2003 Active Directory domain in parallel to the existing Samba domain, anyway, is to use the Active Directory Migration tool (ADMT). From what I'm reading [ADMT works with Samba](http://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2005-June/107028.html) and the process appears to be reasonably painless (it looks just like ADMT'ing from an NT 4.0 domain, to my eyes). I haven't done it myself, but it looks worth trying. At the least, you could spin up a test Samba domain, join a couple of test PCs to it, and do a test migration before running on the production domain.

Edit:

It can still be pretty seamless for the users, though. You can setup a trust relationship between the existing Samba domain and the new Active Directory domain and then migrate computer and user accounts at your own pace.

Comment: It doesn't have to be seamless. I want to build a new DC under a fresh domain name on the same network and www feed. I can then add the machines and users to the new domain. Client machines are due a rebuild anyway. only 6 users btw

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No, there is no seamless way to do this.

Wow.  That's a lot of change.

As Evan said, ADMT is probably your best bet without going with a paid solution.  Build up your Windows DC while everything is still running, and pre-stage a new DHCP server config set to use the new domain's info and IPs

Your best bet is to take an outage weekend (or more; much preferably more) and cut over during that.  You don't want people around while you try to do this.

Comment: It doesn't have to be seamless. I want to build a new DC under a fresh domain name on the same network and www feed. I can then add the machines and users to the new domain. 

Client machines are due a rebuild anyway.

only 6 users btw

Comment: Oh!  In that case, it's a lot easier!  Somehow I had it in mind that it had to be seamless, and that there would be more users...

Comment: I have the new Domain Controller built with Active Directory and DNS Server on it.

At the minute it's on the same switch as everything else. Can't ping it or join the domain.

I've built a test PC to add to AD. The existing user boxes are due to be rebuilt so don't wanna add them to AD just yet.

Any thoughts oh wise'unz?

Thanks again for all the help btw